# Removable (USB) disk eject occasionally gets stuck at "writing data"

Tags: usb, hard-drive, unmount

Ubuntu (Studio) 22.04.

This happens infrequently, but when it happens, it's disruptive because incomplete writes can cause data loss.

For example: Today I copied a 7 MB (mega, not giga) file to a USB SSD -- i.e., fast performance. It should have been instantaneous. Instead, when I ejected the disk to transfer the file to another machine, it popped up the notification warning against removing the disk prematurely ... and the warning never went away.

I did nothing except copy the *one* not-very-big file. There is no action that I took that would cause minutes/hours of continuous disk writes... but continuous disk activity was happening. Normally I don't observe such.

lsof revealed nothing ("lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc -- Output information may be incomplete.").

The SSD was (I think) ntfs formatted out of the box, and I left it that way because I need to transfer files across systems (not all of them are Linux).

Any ideas? What could be causing it or how to prevent it?

Does sysctl have an option to disallow filesystem write caching for removable drives while keeping it enabled for built-in drives? (I've already reduced the write cache because I keep backups on a large but slow external HDD; would not like to turn it off completely but today's behavior was not quite OK with me.)

hjh

Comment: Did you `umount` or eject the device?  so data was actually written to the thumb-drive? rather than just being cached into memory?

Comment: I ejected by clicking the icon in the Thunar file manager. It got stuck writing at this point. I was in a lesson and didn't have the luxury of waiting, so eventually I just pulled the disk and let the Windows machine in the office chkdsk it. However the file hadn't been copied -- directory entry with 0 bytes. So I'd have to guess that some process was thrashing the disk and blocking the file copy. I'd like to find a way to control such background processes if possible b/c a 7 MB file should copy within seconds.